# Test Rails app manually, in the test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, testing, rspec, capybara

I am using Capybara, RSpec, and Selenium to test the filling out and submission of a form in my application. However, despite filling out the form completely, it results in validation errors.

Is there a way to test the form *manually in the browser, in the test environment*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [starting rails in test environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814901/starting-rails-in-test-environment)

Comment: A better alternative is to use [`save_and_open_page`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Asave_and_open_page)  which will show you the exact state of the page at a certain point in your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual testing using automation test is contradictory. Better debug the test :)
You can view what's happening in the browser by entering `BROWSER=chrome` at the beginning of the spec callout in terminal. 
And next thing - if you get validation errors, maybe there's something wrong with your input? Can you show the test and the error here?